# How to make Windows installation files UEFI bootable from hard disk using Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, uefi, windows, 20.10

I created a partition with 8 gigabytes of size formatted to NTFS and copied Windows installation files to that but now I don't know how to make it UEFI bootable to boot the partition and install Windows.

Can anybody help me?
It's worth mentioning that I have searched on the web before and I got that GRUB bootloader should be configured by modifying **grub.cfg** file but I didn't exactly understand how GRUB bootloader should be configured to fulfill this purpose. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

UEFI boot uses FAT32 filesystem to boot from.

You will need to create a FAT32 formatted partition.

About 512MB for just a boot partition is plenty.

Create these directories in the newly formatted FAT32 partition.
:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot

Copy the contents of C:\Windows\boot\EFI to \EFI\Microsoft\boot

You however will need to set up the BCD store with the correct partitions and paths to winload.efi... this cannot be done easily from linux. It can be done, but requires more work than is partical.

Much easier to boot to WinPE and use bootrec.exe or bcdedit.exe tools to complete the configurations.